# How to use ifelse () correctly in R?

Tags: r, if-statement

Given the following code:

```
a <- 3
colors <-  ifelse(a == 3,
c("#004B93", "#389DC3", "#6DBE99"),
ifelse(a == 2, c("#004B93", "#389DC3"), c("#000000", "#000000", "#000000")))
```

My expectation ist to get something like

```
> colors 
[1] "#004B93" "#389DC3" "#6DBE99"
```

But what I get is

```
> colors
[1] "#004B93"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using the wrong function. Use `if(a == 2) c("#004B93", "#389DC3") else c("#000000", "#000000", "#000000")`. You should study `help("ifelse")`. It explains what is going on.

Comment: Or even better: Use `switch`.

Comment: @Roland `switch` is severely limited in what it can do. For one thing, it only works on strings, so it doesn't really work here a priori. `match` would work here, but not better than a simple `if`.

Comment: @Dierforth What is your expected output for other values of `a`? Currently this isn't clear.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The documentation literally says "`EXPR` 
an expression evaluating to a number or a character string." Granted, they would need to transform their numbers to the number of the alternative but it can work just fine.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Judging from their code, the expected output would be `c("#000000", "#000000", "#000000")`. They have two nested `ifelse`.

Comment: @Roland Fair enough, that's of course true. You could do something like `switch(match(the_value, possible_values), …)` — but does that really make sense compared to just using `match` directly? Or, if the values are already consecutive, use direct indexing. `switch` is basically almost completely useless, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use if else statements for check the conditions inside R.

For that you can do the same logic as I checked for you.

```
a <- 3
colors <- if(a == 3) {
c("#004B93", "#389DC3", "#6DBE99")
} else if (a == 2) {
c("#004B93", "#389DC3")
} else {
c("#000000", "#000000", "#000000")
}

print(colors)
```

**Output Result :**

```
[1] "#004B93" "#389DC3" "#6DBE99"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write this:

```
possible_colors = list(
    c("#000000", "#000000", "#000000"),
    c("#004B93", "#389DC3"),
    c("#004B93", "#389DC3", "#6DBE99")
)

colors = if (a < 1L || a > 3L) list[[1L]] else list[[a]]
```

This assumes that `a` only has integer values. Adjust the condition of the `if` accordingly if that is not the case.

If you know that `a` will never be any value except 1, 2 or 3, you can omit the `if` completely and directly write `colors = possible_colors[[a]]`.

Comment: @user2554330 Good point, fixed. You'll notice that I am still assuming integer numbers; this is somewhat intentional, because that's what OP seems to be working with. I could make the test more general, but at the cost of readability, and if I had to guess at OP's use-case I would say that this isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` is a command that is *usually* better to avoid.

Why? Because

```
ifelse(TRUE, 1:3, 4:6)
```

returns `1` and not `1:3`.

In fact, `ifelse` wants the output to be the same length as the test. Above `TRUE` is a vector of length 1, while the candidate output`1:3` is of length 3. However, `ifelse` does not raise any warning, it just *cuts* the vector `1:3`.

There is rationale behind this, and this example should explain it:

```
ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), yes = 1:3, no = 4:6)
[1] 1 5 3
```

True values are taken from the `yes` argument and false values are
taken from the `no` argument. If you really want this sophisticate behaviour, `ifelse` can be extremely powerful, but this is rarely what you want.

The good news is that R is a functional language, thus everything is a function, including the if/else construct. Hence, to get the intended result from

```
ret <- ifelse(TRUE, 1:3, 4:6)
```

rewrite it like so:

```
ret <- if(TRUE) 1:3 else 4:6
```

and `ret` is `1:3`

Do you need nested conditions? No problem.

```
a <- 1 
ret <- if(a == 1) 1:3 else (if(a == 2) 4:6 else 7:9)
```

The line above emphasises the functional approach, where I replace the expression `4:6` with the bracketed one, but it can be shortened to:

```
ret <- if(a == 1) 1:3 else if(a == 2) 4:6 else 7:9
```

However, let me note that for this type of tasks, there is a dedicated R function: `switch`.

```
ret <- switch(a, 1:3, 4:6, 7:9)
```

Counting after `a`, the first, second, etc. argument is chosen depending on the value of `a`, thus:

```
a <- 2
switch(a, 1:3, 4:6, 7:9)
# 4:6
```

As for your case:

```
a <- 3
switch(a, 
       c("#000000", "#000000", "#000000"),
       c("#004B93", "#389DC3"), 
       c("#004B93", "#389DC3", "#6DBE99"))

# [1] "#004B93" "#389DC3" "#6DBE99"
```